# Assembly and Win32API input output

Tags: winapi, assembly, console, masm, irvine32

I am trying to figure this out but am stumped a bit. What I am trying to do is to use the `ReadConsole`/`WriteConsole` functions from the win32 lib and got it to work a degree but just not there. I am having trouble getting the second write console working correctly. I don't think I am sending the buffer to the variable right. I must be missing something here and I dont know what it is. 
Here is what I have so far

```
TITLE MASM Template                     (main.asm)

  ; Description:
  ; 
   ; Revision date:

 INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
 BufSize = 80
 .data
  endl EQU <0dh,0ah>            ; end of line sequence

 ;variable holders
 firstN db ?
 fNSize db ($-firstN)

 ;messages for getting input
 fName LABEL BYTE
BYTE "Enter your first name", endl
 fNameSize DWORD ($-fName)

 ;output handlers
 consoleHandle HANDLE 0     ; handle to standard output device
 bytesWritten  DWORD ?      ; number of bytes written

 ;input handlers
 buffer BYTE BufSize DUP(?)
 stdInHandle HANDLE ?
 bytesRead   DWORD ?

 .code
 main PROC
 ; Get the console output handle:
    INVOKE GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
  mov consoleHandle,eax

  ; Write a string to the console:
INVOKE WriteConsole,
  consoleHandle,        ; console output handle
  ADDR fName,           ; string pointer
  fNameSize,            ; string length
  ADDR bytesWritten,    ; returns num bytes written
  0                     ; not used

   ; Get handle to standard input
INVOKE GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
   mov   stdInHandle,eax

   ; Wait for user input
 INVOKE ReadConsole, stdInHandle, ADDR buffer,
  BufSize, ADDR bytesRead, 0

 ;cheack to see if read consol worked
  mov esi, OFFSET buffer
  mov ecx, bytesRead
  mov ebx, TYPE buffer
  call DumpMem

 ;move the input into the variable
  mov firstN, TYPE  buffer



   ; Write a string to the console:
INVOKE WriteConsole,
  consoleHandle,        ; console output handle
  ADDR firstN,          ; string pointer
  fNSize,           ; string length
  ADDR bytesWritten,    ; returns num bytes written
  0                     ; not used


INVOKE ExitProcess,0
   main ENDP
  END main
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You don't say what's wrong with the second WriteConsole call, but I'm guessing you only get one byte of output.  Am I right?

Comment: I think that right it seams to only give me a smiley looking face which is kinda nice but not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstN and fNSize are each a single byte and that's not what you want.  Simply do this for the second WriteConsole call:

```
INVOKE WriteConsole,
  consoleHandle,        ; console output handle
  ADDR buffer,          ; string pointer
  bytesRead,            ; string length
  ADDR bytesWritten,    ; returns num bytes written
  0                     ; not used
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to send what is in the buffer into a variable for storage?

Comment: Of course, but you need to allocate a buffer as large as bytesRead to store it, and then you need to copy the contents of buffer to it.  You could dynamically allocate it with HeapAlloc or something similar.

Comment: could I use the stack to store the contents of the buffer then mov that to the variable?

Comment: Sure, but you need to manage the stack pointer yourself.  As long as you do that properly you should be okay.